# Should I replace my Colorado Blue Spruces?

Tags: trees, spruces

I have two Colorado Blue spruces, both looked to be damaged at installation. One is missing about 2 feet area of twigs near the top. They looked to have broken off during transit? The other has had its top broken off.

Should I rip them out and start again? Will the side branches grow back again? Will it look terrible?

They are both around 13 feet tall.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you choose these specimens at the nursery?  This is not at all abnormal for blue spruce.  These bare spaces seem to be old, not new as in damaged in transit.  If you have a problem with these two trees you need to talk to the nursery right now.  Have a supervisor come out to check the install.  Were these trees planted correctly (not too deep), how close are they to structures to each other?  20 feet from a building or from another spruce would be normal.  Did they remove the burlap from the ball?  Did they plant on undisturbed subsoil?  Take note of all obviously newly broken branches.

Comment: A landscaper we hired installed these last summer. They seemed to have snapped branches when they installed them 1 year ago. I dont think the burlap was removed and they are well spaced relative to the fence/other trees.

Comment: That burlap should have been removed.  Especially if it had green tints to it...a sulfur chemical that inhibits root growth OUT of the burlap.  Ugh!  Make sure all twine is cut that will constrict the cambium, all labels.  These trees will be fine left alone.  If you are not happy with these trees you HAVE to contact this dealer now.  I would love to see a picture of the soil and trunk connection.  If these trees were planted too low or the subsoil they sit upon was disturbed this landscaper will cause you to lose your investment.  A few branches snapped is okay, normal.  But the leader is...